# How to pass a custom struct into a _variant_t in C++ (non-CLI)?

Tags: c++, struct, variant, safearray

I'm trying to pass a struct e. g.:

```
struct SVec3
{
public:
    float X;
    float Y;
    float Z;
};
```

into a _variant_t, to store it in an SAFEARRAY. My approach for that is first creating an instance:

```
SVec3 rot;
rot.X = 0.1f;
rot.Y = 0.65f;
rot.Z = 0.01f;
```

Then i fit it via reference into a _variant_t

```
_variant_t var((IUnknown*)&rot, true);
```

And store it in the SAFEARRAY:

```
LONG index = 0;
SAFEARRAY* psaArgs = SafeArrayCreateVector(VT_VARIANT, 0, 1);
SafeArrayPutElement(psaArgs, &index, &var);  // This throws a memory access exception.
```

So what is my mistake here? Is there an other way to do that? If so, how should I pass a SAFEARRAY of those structs into a SAFEARRAY? Is there a common way? Or am I missing something like a Recorddescription, because in this way the SAFEARRAY doesn't contain the data, it contains Pointers to the Data. But how to store the data in a SAFEARRAY?

Regards Nem

Comment: I haven't tried it, but looking in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221673\(v=VS.85\)) it looks like you might want the type to be `VT_ARRAY | VT_R4`.

Comment: You cannot bypass VT_RECORD and IRecordInfo here.  Enough link soup already but the canonical MSDN library page is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221453%28v=VS.85%29

Comment: Why don't you store it as a SAFEARRAY of 3 elements, each of which is a float?

Answer (score 3):

You're casting a SVec3 pointer to a pointer to IUnknown interface.  Your data structure is a simple data type and not a full-blown class implementing IUnknown.  So your application breaks as soon as Windows tries to call methods on IUnknown.

Some quick Googling reveals some links that might be useful in regards to variants and user defined types:

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vclanguage/thread/38dca037-f6da-43dc-8fa3-0358638681ce
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221039(VS.85).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221210(VS.85).aspx
- Especially for you:  Passing a Safearray of UDTs:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221212(VS.85).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221543(VS.85).aspx

You'll have to start with putting your UDT in a type library...

Comment: Exactly this links i'm looking at for some hours by now.

Comment: The topic "Passing a Safearray of UDTs" seems like it should be especially useful for your application... have you tried it?

Comment: I've got no idea what syntax it is but my compiler says "NO". Looks like CLI or something like that. Especially i'm talking about typedef [uuid(D8B3861A-74C6-11d2-A0D6-00C04FB17CDB)] struct tagStudentStruct ....

Comment: That portion is Interface Description Language, not C++.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367091(VS.85).aspx.  Basically you use a different compiler (MIDL) for it to compile it into a type library, which you include as a Windows resource in your program's EXE.  You can use OLEVIEW.EXE to look at IDL for various libraries installed on your computer to get an idea of things.  Also MIDL can output C/C++ header files you can use.

Comment: If this is all way over your head, you may do well to use 3 separate arrays: an array of X, an array of Y, and of Z.  Then you can use arrays of primitive types (float) instead of a user-defined type in a type library.

Comment: Okay, to clarify that. I've got a .NET-Assembly and i need to get the TypeInfo of my struct there. The same struct i need to define in my native application due this TypeInfo. But what happens if the .NET-Assembly is recompiled and the TypeInfo is changes? If i understand it right i need to port it by hand. Isn't there an easy way to port it as sequential data which can be marshalled into that type? *edit* Ah your last part sounds easier and more

Comment: But really 3 separate arrays and not one which contains sequential data?

Comment: One array with sequential data would work too.  You'd have to do a little math to access the elements but it would be fine.

Comment: If you want to use UDT there would be two ways.  First do as mentioned and have your C++ DLL store a type library, compiled using MIDL.  To use the type in .NET you'll add a COM reference in .NET to your unmanaged COM DLL.  This makes a COM interop assembly containing your struct.  The struct is defined in only one place in source code: the IDL of the type library; everything else is automatic.  Alternatively you can have your .NET DLL export a type library with the user-defined type that gets referenced by your C++ DLL.  But I'm not as familiar with that method, though I know it's possible.

Comment: I've got it working to get the safearray, but at least my call after that fails because it didnt understand the implicitly defined cast inside the .NET-assembly. But maybe there still is a possibility. In the specifications i saw that i can get the TypeInfo of a .NET-Type. Its easy to get that from the loaded assembly. Now I am looking whether it helps to solve that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Long topic, long day. I don't want to register my assembly as COM object (this would be against the my requirements for that project), so I have to avoid that COM-Stuff. For that I've done a workaround. Here is an example to illustrate that (C# Assemblycode):

```
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public float[] INTEROP_Position
    {
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArraySubType = VarEnum.VT_R4)]
        get { return (float[])this.Position; }
        [param: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArraySubType = VarEnum.VT_R4)]
        set { this.Position = (DataTypes.Vec3)value; }
    }

    // Inside the Vec3 Definition:
    public static explicit operator Vec3(float[] arr)
    {
        if (arr.Length != 3) throw new Exception("The array must have a length of 3.");
        return new Vec3(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]);
    }

    public static explicit operator float[](Vec3 vec3)
    {
        return new float[] { vec3.X, vec3.Y, vec3.Z };
    }
```

On C++ side i marshall it by hand

```
_variant_t Convert::svec3tovar(SVec3 vec) {
    LONG index = 0;
    SAFEARRAY* psaStruct = SafeArrayCreateVector(VT_R4, 0, 3);
    SafeArrayPutElement(psaStruct, &index, &vec.X);
    index = 1;
    SafeArrayPutElement(psaStruct, &index, &vec.Y);
    index = 2;
    SafeArrayPutElement(psaStruct, &index, &vec.Z);

    VARIANT vV ;
    vV.vt = VT_ARRAY | VT_R4;
    vV.parray = psaStruct;  
    return _variant_t(vV);
}
```

and back

```
SVec3 Convert::vartosvec3(_variant_t var) {
    SVec3 vec;
    SAFEARRAY* psaStruct = var.parray;
    LONG index = 0;
    SafeArrayGetElement(psaStruct, &index, &vec.X);
    index = 1;
    SafeArrayGetElement(psaStruct, &index, &vec.Y);
    index = 2;
    SafeArrayGetElement(psaStruct, &index, &vec.Z);
    return vec;
}
```

And it works great. Without all that COM stuff. :)

I know the real answer for that was given by James, but to avoid COM this is my answer. Maybe user786653's comment was the correct answer to solve my problem.
But thank you James (and the others), for your invested time.

/Solved